# Hand-drawn physics objects in AndEngine

Tags: android, drawing, collision-detection, game-physics, andengine

I found that
"Chalk Ball has been developed with [andengine and Box2D as physics engine](http://www.andengine.org/)".

Chalk ball is a physics game. You can draw a line by your finger and it will be a physics object. How can I make such effect? Do I need to use particle systems to create custom curve lines? And how can I build them like physics objects?
Or it will be a polygon with many points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked developer of the ChalkBall about the method and he answered:

"*It is a sequence of Rectangles, but I am warning you in advance, AndEngine has quite some flaws and weirdness. Not sure of which version you are using, but the one of January is quite defective and I had to do many workarounds.*"

Comment: I'm not aware of a "quite defective" version of AndEngine that needs "many workarounds" -- and I should know. At least nothing severe was reported so far. =/

Comment: I don't think that newest version of AndEngine is deffective, i only post a quote =) I think that this engine is very poverfull and i found a simple answer on my question) Thx for such an engine.